# Pandas: Complex merge of DataFrames with date basis

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, date, dataframe

I have 2 pandas `DataFrame`'s that I need to merge in a bit of a complex manner so I am in need of some help.

#### DataFrame to be inserted:

```
            AAPL shares  GOOG shares  MSFT shares
date                                             
2019-01-01          0.0         10.0          0.0
2019-01-05          0.0          0.0         15.0
2019-01-12          0.0          0.0          7.0
2019-01-13          3.0          0.0          0.0
2019-01-14          0.0         -5.0          0.0
```

#### DataFrame to receive insertion

```
               0      1           2        3           4       5
0     1998-01-02  16.25  2014-03-27   558.46  1998-01-02  131.13
1     1998-01-05  15.88  2014-03-28   559.99  1998-01-05  130.38
2     1998-01-06  18.94  2014-03-31   556.97  1998-01-06  131.13
3     1998-01-07  17.50  2014-04-01   567.16  1998-01-07  129.56
4     1998-01-08  18.19  2014-04-02   567.00  1998-01-08  130.50
5     1998-01-09  18.19  2014-04-03   569.74  1998-01-09  127.00
6     1998-01-12  18.25  2014-04-04   543.14  1998-01-12  129.50
7     1998-01-13  19.50  2014-04-07   538.15  1998-01-13  132.13
8     1998-01-14  19.75  2014-04-08   554.90  1998-01-14  131.13
9     1998-01-15  19.19  2014-04-09   564.14  1998-01-15  132.31
10    1998-01-16  18.81  2014-04-10   540.95  1998-01-16  135.25
11    1998-01-20  19.06  2014-04-11   530.60  1998-01-20  137.81
12    1998-01-21  18.91  2014-04-14   532.52  1998-01-21  137.00
13    1998-01-22  19.25  2014-04-15   536.44  1998-01-22  138.63
14    1998-01-23  19.50  2014-04-16   556.54  1998-01-23  138.25
15    1998-01-26  19.44  2014-04-17   536.10  1998-01-26  141.75
```

1) The `receiving_df` needs to establish a common basis for `date` (notice column `2` is different), thus the `DataFrame` needs to be organized into `date`, `1`, `3`, `5` where the dates of `0`, `2`, and `4` are used for assembling `date` to correctly reflect the values in `1`, `3`, `5` at a certain date.

Sample output from step 1:

```
               0      1       3       5
0     1998-01-02  16.25      NA  131.13
1     1998-01-05  15.88      NA  130.38
2     1998-01-06  18.94      NA  131.13
3     1998-01-07  17.50      NA  129.56
4     1998-01-08  18.19      NA  130.50
5     1998-01-09  18.19      NA  127.00
6     1998-01-12  18.25      NA  129.50
7     1998-01-13  19.50      NA  132.13
8     1998-01-14  19.75      NA  131.13
...
10    2014-04-10  18.81  558.46  135.25
11    2014-04-11  19.06  559.99  137.81
12    2014-04-14  18.91  556.97  137.00
13    2014-04-15  19.25  567.16  138.63
14    2014-04-16  19.50  567.00  138.25
15    2014-04-17  19.44  569.74  141.75
...
```

2) `inserting_df` will need to be sorted by date according to `receiving_df['date']` and the columns `AAPL shares`, `GOOG shares`, `MSFT shares` will be added as columns in the `receiving_df`. I imagine this will follow similar methods as in 1).

Sample output from step 2:

```
               0   AAPL shares   1      GOOG shares       3   MSFT shares        5
0     1998-01-02           0.0   16.25          0.0       NA          0.0   131.13
1     1998-01-05           0.0   15.88          0.0       NA          0.0   130.38
2     1998-01-06           0.0   18.94          0.0       NA          0.0   131.13
3     1998-01-07           0.0   17.50          0.0       NA          0.0   129.56
4     1998-01-08           0.0   18.19          0.0       NA          0.0   130.50
5     1998-01-09           0.0   18.19          0.0       NA          0.0   127.00
6     1998-01-12           0.0   18.25          0.0       NA          0.0   129.50
7     1998-01-13           0.0   19.50          0.0       NA          0.0   132.13
8     1998-01-14           0.0   19.75          0.0       NA          0.0   131.13
...                                     
10    2014-04-10           0.0   18.81          0.0   558.46          0.0   135.25
11    2014-04-11           0.0   19.06          0.0   559.99          0.0   137.81
12    2014-04-14           0.0   18.91          0.0   556.97          0.0   137.00
13    2014-04-15           0.0   19.25          0.0   567.16          0.0   138.63
14    2014-04-16           0.0   19.50          0.0   567.00          0.0   138.25
15    2014-04-17           0.0   19.44          0.0   569.74          0.0   141.75
...            
<#>   2019-01-01           0.0   <value>       10.0   <value>         0.0   <value>  
<#>   2019-01-02           0.0   <value>        0.0   <value>        15.0   <value>
<#>   2019-01-03           0.0   <value>        0.0   <value>         7.0   <value>
<#>   2019-01-04           3.0   <value>        0.0   <value>         0.0   <value>
<#>   2019-01-05           0.0   <value>       -5.0   <value>         0.0   <value>
```

3) The new columns `AAPL shares`, `GOOG shares`, `MSFT shares` will need to be filled forward with cumsum but I think I got that down:
~ `df.set_index('date').sort_index().fillna(value=0).cumsum())`

Sample output from step 3:

```
               0   AAPL shares   1      GOOG shares       3   MSFT shares        5
0     1998-01-02           0.0   16.25          0.0       NA          0.0   131.13
1     1998-01-05           0.0   15.88          0.0       NA          0.0   130.38
2     1998-01-06           0.0   18.94          0.0       NA          0.0   131.13
3     1998-01-07           0.0   17.50          0.0       NA          0.0   129.56
4     1998-01-08           0.0   18.19          0.0       NA          0.0   130.50
5     1998-01-09           0.0   18.19          0.0       NA          0.0   127.00
6     1998-01-12           0.0   18.25          0.0       NA          0.0   129.50
7     1998-01-13           0.0   19.50          0.0       NA          0.0   132.13
8     1998-01-14           0.0   19.75          0.0       NA          0.0   131.13
...
10    2014-04-10           0.0   18.81          0.0   558.46          0.0   135.25
11    2014-04-11           0.0   19.06          0.0   559.99          0.0   137.81
12    2014-04-14           0.0   18.91          0.0   556.97          0.0   137.00
13    2014-04-15           0.0   19.25          0.0   567.16          0.0   138.63
14    2014-04-16           0.0   19.50          0.0   567.00          0.0   138.25
15    2014-04-17           0.0   19.44          0.0   569.74          0.0   141.75
...
<#>   2019-01-01           0.0   <value>       10.0   <value>         0.0   <value>
<#>   2019-01-02           0.0   <value>       10.0   <value>        15.0   <value>
<#>   2019-01-03           0.0   <value>       10.0   <value>        22.0   <value>
<#>   2019-01-04           3.0   <value>       10.0   <value>        22.0   <value>
<#>   2019-01-05           3.0   <value>        5.0   <value>        22.0   <value>
```

So the end goal would result in the values and shares held according to the `date` index. For `date`'s that will not have a column `2` value (since column `2` is "missing" some dates) in the resulting `receiving_df`, it would be best to make that value `N/A` but 0 would suffice.

Happy to clarify anything, I appreciate any/all help as this is a very complex operation (at least for me), thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Trying to merge in a loop now since number of `date`-`value` pairs may vary. I now have a list of separate `DataFrames` for the `date`-`value` pairs: `dfs_list`. Since number of pairs may vary, it seems best not to `set_index` based on column labels hence `set_index(rec_df.columns[0])`.

```
rec_df = dfs_list[0].set_index(dfs_list[0].columns[0])
for dataframe in range(len(dfs_list)-1):
            rec_df = pd.merge(left=rec_df, right=dfs_list[dataframe+1].set_index(dfs_list[dataframe+1].columns[0]),
                              left_index=True, right_index=True,
                              how='outer')
```

Comment: It's pretty unclear exactly what you're asking. An example of your preferred output would be very helpful, I think, as in this case one of the dates match and therefore the data wouldn't be inserted at all. Additionally, does the date in `insert_df` correlate to the date(s) in `receive_df` in columns 0/4, or in column 2? This looks like a fairly straightforward `pd.merge()` between the two, but the added explanation makes it sound more complicated in a way I can't quite seem to grasp

Comment: My apologies, I will revise explanation and provide sample output momentarily

Comment: @G.Anderson Please see my updated edits to reflect a sample output at each step until completion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your clarifications, here's what I understand a solution to be.

Given the dataframes given, I added column names to make things more clear, and renamed `receive_df` to just `df` to save on typing:

```
df.columns=['d1','p1','d2','p2','d3','p3']

df1=pd.merge(left=df[['d1','p1']].set_index('d1'),right=df[['d3','p3']].set_index('d3'), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')

df1.head()

            p1      p3
d1      
1998-01-02  16.25   131.13
1998-01-05  15.88   130.38
1998-01-06  18.94   131.13
1998-01-07  17.50   129.56
1998-01-08  18.19   130.50

rec_df=pd.merge(left=df1,right=df[['d2','p2']].set_index('d2'),left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')

rec_df

            p1      p3      p2
1998-01-02  16.25   131.13  NaN
1998-01-05  15.88   130.38  NaN
1998-01-06  18.94   131.13  NaN
1998-01-07  17.50   129.56  NaN
1998-01-08  18.19   130.50  NaN
1998-01-09  18.19   127.00  NaN
1998-01-12  18.25   129.50  NaN
1998-01-13  19.50   132.13  NaN
1998-01-14  19.75   131.13  NaN
1998-01-15  19.19   132.31  NaN
1998-01-16  18.81   135.25  NaN
1998-01-20  19.06   137.81  NaN
1998-01-21  18.91   137.00  NaN
1998-01-22  19.25   138.63  NaN
1998-01-23  19.50   138.25  NaN
1998-01-26  19.44   141.75  NaN
2014-03-27  NaN NaN 558.46
2014-03-28  NaN NaN 559.99
2014-03-31  NaN NaN 556.97
2014-04-01  NaN NaN 567.16
2014-04-02  NaN NaN 567.00
2014-04-03  NaN NaN 569.74
2014-04-04  NaN NaN 543.14
2014-04-07  NaN NaN 538.15
2014-04-08  NaN NaN 554.90
2014-04-09  NaN NaN 564.14
2014-04-10  NaN NaN 540.95
2014-04-11  NaN NaN 530.60
2014-04-14  NaN NaN 532.52
2014-04-15  NaN NaN 536.44
2014-04-16  NaN NaN 556.54
2014-04-17  NaN NaN 536.10
```

Now, here's where I couldn't test, since your insert df has no matching date indices from your receive df, but that *should* look like

```
final_df=pd.merge(left=rec_df, right=insert_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, dropna=False)
```

Of course, this assumes that the `date` column is set as the index already as in your sample. If you want a numerical index at the end, you can `reset_index(in_place=True)`, or you can leave the date as the index.

It looks like you already have a handle on the last part of the task, and I can't test it anyway with the given data.

And note also that you can reorder the columns however you want depending how you want your output to look (`df=df[[list of columns in order]]`)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I guess I should have mentioned that the number of columns in `receiving_df`/`df` may vary so how would this change `left` and `right` in `merge`? Also, I have no way of knowing which `d#` columns will match, in this case it was pretty clear that `d2` was the outlier and `d1` & `d3` were the same however this may not always be the case.

Comment: Is there a way to "interpolate" columns into each other?

Comment: Unless you tell it otherwise, pandas will merge all columns, joining on a column or, in this case, the index. As for the rest, see my edits for if you're unsure how much data matches between columns. In that case, you can join the columns on date still, but pass it `how='outer'` to keep all dates and fill with `NaN` where they don't match

Comment: Please see my EDIT and result in trying to apply your logic in a loop since `date`-`value` pairs will vary. Not only do the numbers seem off based on their positions but I can't truly check because the `date` column is gone

Comment: In your initial sample of `insert_df`, the index is the date. If that's how it is in your actual data, then when you set your index to column `0`, then it sets the index to the `AAPL shares` column. Am I misunderstanding your data? To be honest, I would name the columns something meaningful and pass it explicitly rather than by index, if possible.

Comment: Also, are you able to get it working for one df first before you attempt to loop? And if so, what is that output, and how does the first insert_df differ from the second?

Comment: Based on your latest suggestion, I updated my edit - it works beautifully. I just need it in a loop now (and then still need to do step 3 but like I said, I imagine it will follow similar method)

Comment: Got it - see EDIT, on to step 2

Comment: Well done, glad you could solve it! Feel free to accept the answer if it did what you needed or wait for a better one

Comment: As soon as I get step 2 Ill be sure to accept, I still need to insert the df